# Is Hotmail blocking some CSS properties when send mail with PHP?

Tags: php, html, hotmail

I am trying to put a form inside a mail from my website.

I just discovered that in Hotmail, `float:left;` and `float:right;` doesn’t seems to work, even in a HTML e-mail.

Is there any way to get around it?

Comment: show your code or you will get -1s

Comment: should be easy to  check with view source and something like firebug

Comment: if your sending to regular email clients you should be aware they support a very different set of html than a browser does

Comment: Exactly. I told you guys that my e-mail has already all the necessary headers for a HTML e-mail. All I wanted to know is the reasons why some css doesnt work at all. ANd someone has answered profesionnaly +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is Hotmail blocking some CSS properties when send mail with PHP?

100% nothing to do with Hotmail specifically or PHP specifically, but the sad state of HTML e-mail design in general.

Hotmail & others will not use `float` values in CSS. In fact HTML e-mail is—in general—archaic and will force you to engage in design techniques that go all the way back to nested `<table>` layout practices of the 1990s.  As explained on this page on [“Email Design Guidelines” from Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/); emphasis mine:

> Before getting into the details, there are some uncomfortable facts
>   that those new to HTML email should be aware of. Building an email is
>   not like building for the web. **While web browsers continue their
>   onward march towards standards, many email clients have stubbornly
>   stayed put. Some have even gone backwards.** In 2007, Microsoft switched
>   the Outlook rendering engine from Internet Explorer to Word. Yes, as
>   in the word processor. Add to this the quirks of the major web-based
>   email clients like Gmail and Outlook.com, sprinkle in a little Lotus
>   Notes and you’ll soon realize how different the email game is.

Which is all to say if you think you can simply take HTML & CSS code from your main website to repurpose as a pure HTML e-mail you are in for a very rude awakening. The world of HTML e-mail design is a whole world of design headaches unto itself.

Another good resource on the topic can be found in [“The Foundations of Coding HTML Email” from Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/html-email-coding-101-infographic); again the emphasis is mine:

> Simply put, many HTML and CSS properties used in modern web design are
>   not supported in email. Email programs like Outlook 2007 and 2010
>   actually use Microsoft Word (yes, a word processor) to render HTML. In
>   other words, **building an email is not like building a website, unless
>   you’re still building websites like we did back in 1999.**

They even include this great—and head noddingly well structured—“Email Coding 101” graphic explaining what you need to know when designing HTML e-mails. Yes, it’s not pleasant but this is the sad reality of HTML e-mails in 2014.

[image]

Comment: +100 spent a few more hours than i would like on html email over the years. one of my bookmarked resources: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: 95 you just a noob :-)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all that explanation! This is more than I expected :) Thanks a lot!!